# Индексируемые коллекции с итератором

Tags: c#, .net, коллекции

Несколько взаимосвязаных вопросов в одном.

**Вопрос 1:** Предположим есть индексируемая коллекция, которая также реализует доступ к её элементам через итератор. Обязан ли итератор такой коллекции возвращать элементы в порядке возрастания индекса? Т.е., скажем, вот такая коллекция-обёртка:

```
class Shuffle<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    IReadOnlyList<T> _internal;

    public int Count { get { return _internal.Count; } }
    public T this[int i] { get { return _internal[i]; } }

    public Shuffle(IReadOnlyList<T> elements)
    {
        if (elements == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        _internal = elements;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>(_internal.Count);
        indexes.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, _internal.Count));

        while (indexes.Count > 0)
        {
            int i = rnd.Next(indexes.Count);
            int ix = indexes[i];
            indexes.RemoveAt(i);
            yield return _internal[ix];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return _internal.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

будет ли нарушать какие-то общепринятые стандарты?

**Вопрос 2:** При работе со стандартными коллекциями, такими как `T[]` или `List<T>`, если **важен порядок** доступа к элементам коллекции, можно ли не опасаясь<sup>(*)</sup> заменять, например, такую конструкцию

```
char[] ch_arr = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
for (int i = 0; i < ch_arr.Length; i++)
    Console.Write(ch_arr[i]);
```

на такую:

```
char[] ch_arr = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
foreach (char c in ch_arr)
    Console.Write(c);
```

?

---

(*) - следующего, к примеру, сценария. Вышло обновление ядра, память под массив больше не выделяется одним куском, а может быть выделена блоками, реализация итератора для массива (в угоду быстродействию) была изменена, и элементы теперь могут возвращаться не в логическом порядке, а в каком-то произвольном. Или сегодня пишем под одну платформу, а завтра этот код нужно переносить на другую, где такая вот особенность.

Comment: Но ведь правила сайта запрещают задавать несколько вопросов в одном посте, разве не так?

Comment: @Schullz, По сути это один вопрос, просто в нём две части. Ответ на одну часть проливает свет на вторую и наоборот (по крайней мере мне так кажется).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В случае "просто итератора" - нет, не обязан. Более того, есть коллекции (из ASP.NET), которые перечисляют не свои значения - а свои ключи, что бывает очень неожиданно.

Но у вас не просто коллекция, у вас реализация [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx). А для списка семантика этих операций однозначна (хоть ее и забыли документировать явно) - перечисление всегда идет подряд. Таким образом оно работает в стандартных коллекциях - и вам надо делать свои совместимым образом.

Отсюда и второй момент - да, заменять один цикл на другой обычно безопасно. Я говорю обычно - потому что у циклов `for` и `foreach` разная область видимости  переменных цикла.

Comment: _"забыли документировать явно"_ - это настораживает. _"Таким образом оно работает в стандартных коллекциях"_ всё-таки непонятно, оно так работает, потому что таковы существующие реализации, или потому, что так должно быть (того требует стандарт, спецификация и т.п.)? Скажем в .Net реализациях MS и Mono в итераторах массива в `MoveNext()` делается `index++`. Если появится другая реализация, где будет иначе, будет ли это нарушением стандартов/спецификаций? Приведу аналогию из SQL. Там есть `select` и `select ... order by ...`. Почему-то у меня `foreach` ассоциируется с 1-м, а `for` со 2-м.

Comment: @i-one зря ассоциируется. Список - он всегда упорядоченный. Неупорядоченная (точнее, необязательно упорядоченная) коллекция - это уже интерфейс `ICollection<>`